# QGraphicsScene "itemAt()" not detecting QGraphicsEllipsesItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I've got a Qt application implemented consisting of a `main window` with a custom `QWidget` called `CanvasWidget` that has a `QGraphicsScene` and `view` in which items are drawn.

The objects are visible and drawn correctly, however, when testing for functionality, `itemAt` always returns false.  Here is an example:

Creation of point in separate widget:

`drawGraphic` is a signal connected to `addGraphic`, a slot (pointradius = 2)

```
    case(PointType):
        //draw point
        pnt = new QGraphicsEllipseItem();
        pnt->setRect(exp.head.value.point_value.x - pointradius, exp.head.value.point_value.y - pointradius, pointradius * 2, pointradius * 2);
        pnt->setBrush(Qt::black);
        drawGraphic(pnt);
        break;
```

CanvasWidget::addGraphic:

```
void CanvasWidget::addGraphic(QGraphicsItem * item){
    scene->addItem(item);
    scene->update();
    qDebug() << item->scenePos();
}
```

Test code:

```
void TestGUI::testPoint() {

  QVERIFY(repl && replEdit);
  QVERIFY(canvas && scene);

  // send a string to the repl widget
  QTest::keyClicks(replEdit, "(draw (point 0 0))");
  QTest::keyClick(replEdit, Qt::Key_Return, Qt::NoModifier);

  // check canvas
  QVERIFY2(scene->itemAt(QPointF(0, 0), QTransform()) != 0,
           "Expected a point in the scene. Not found.");
}
```

Output:

```
QDEBUG : TestGUI::testPoint() QPointF(0,0)
QDEBUG : TestGUI::testPoint() QPointF(0,0)
FAIL!  : TestGUI::testPoint() 'scene->itemAt(QPointF(0, 0), QTransform()) != 0' 
returned FALSE. (Expected a point in the scene. Not found.)
```

[QPointF(0,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9XHz.png)

I am fairly new to Qt and am sure that I have made a simple mistake somewhere here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So your ellipse is covering the origin of the scene (0,0)?

Comment: Yes. Dunno if it's helpful but I'll add a screenshot of the window output after adding the point.

Comment: Neither your code nor your screenshot proves that 0,0 is fully covered by an item. Did you try explicitely setting up an item at that location?